# Can I easily add new directives to Template Toolkit for Perl?

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I'd like to add my own directives to Template Toolkit instead if adding functions and/or virtual methods via the plugin system. Is this easily doable without delving too deep into `Template::Grammar`? And are there any examples I could study on CPAN?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the [MACRO directive](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Directives.html#section_MACRO) which is described in Template::Manual do what you want?

Comment: Almost, but I guess the limitations of MACRO suggests a negative answer to my question since I'm seeking to implement custom grammar for the directives, to boot. I didn't specify as much, though, so this is technically correct.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I've found the best way to extend TT's behaviour is to shove subrefs in the stash:

```
$stash = { clever => \&do_something};
```

Comment: might not be appropriate for this question (custom grammars, etc), but good practice in general - has the advantage that tests can easily be written for `do_something()`, whilst avoiding trying to implement too much code from the templates